# Is there a proper way to use CSS constants in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to use constants in CSS files with React. My current approach is to use CSS variables in a separate constants file, then import this file into my App.tsx file. This makes it available everywhere for use. For example:

In constants.css:

```
:root{
--bg-color: white;
}
```

In component.css:

```
.class {
color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

In App.tsx:

```
import "./constants.css";
```

This works, but I want to make sure I'm adhering to best practice. Is there a better approach?

Comment: "Best approach" can be debated, although what you are doing seems to be a stable method. Other CSS frameworks such as Material UI Design also have a global style sheet (similar to what you are doing) that is imported into the App and accessible in any component it is needed. Global constants are effectively used written once and reusable elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

I use another way to do that.

```
documet.body.style.setAttribute("--clr-primary", "hsl(185, 100%, 40%)")
```

whe `document.body` ==>  element.

the code above create (or edit) a new custom css property with name: `--clr-primary` and set the value as `hsl(185, 100%, 40%)`.
It looks like this code in css:

```
body {
   --clr-priamry: hsl(185, 100%, 40%);
}
```